# Plot lines between points in a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, line

I have a matrix with n rows and 4 columns. The columns are x0, y0, and x1, y1 (so basically I have n pairs of point coordinates in 2D). I want to draw a line between corresponding point pairs (that is, only between x0, y0 and x1, y1 of one row).

Is it possible to do it without a loop? Because the following works but is very slow.

```
for i = 1:size(A.data, 1)
    plot([A.data(i, 1), A.data(i, 3)], [A.data(i, 2), A.data(i, 4)], 'k-')
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for the data structure I have:

```
data = [
        0, 0, 1, 0;...
        1, 0, 1, 1;...
        1, 1, 0, 1;...
        0, 1, 0, 0 ...
       ];

figure(1);
hold off;

%slow way
for i = 1:size(data, 1)
    plot([data(i, 1) data(i, 3)], [data(i, 2) data(i, 4)], 'r-');
    hold on;
end

%fast way ("vectorized")
    plot([data(:, 1)' data(:, 3)'], [data(:, 2)' data(:, 4)'], 'b-');
axis equal
```

This particular example draws a square.

The key is that MATLAB draws lines *column-wise* in the arguments. That is, if the arguments of `plot` have *n* columns, the line will have *n*-1 segments.

In a "connect-the-dots" scenario where all points in the vectors must be connected, this is irrelevant because MATLAB will transpose to get a column vector if it needs to. It becomes important in my application because I do *not* want to connect every point on the list - only pairs of points.

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for the same answer.  I basically want a horizontal line for each x,y point, starting with that point's x-y value, and ending at the x value of the next xy pair, without a line joining that segment to that of the next xy pair.  I can make the segments by adding new points between, with the old y and the new x, but I didn't know how to break up the line segments.  But your wording (matrix) gave me an idea.  What if you load your xy pairs to a pair of x, y vectors and - wait for it - separate your pairs with nan's in both the x and y vectors.  I tried that with a very long sine wave, and it seems to work.  A ton of disjoint line segments, that plot and zoom instantly. :)  See if it solves your problem.

```
% LinePairsTest.m
% Test fast plot and zoom of a bunch of lines between disjoint pairs of points 
% Solution: put pairs of x1,y1:x2,y2 into one x and one y vector, but with
% pairs separated by x and or y = nan.  Nan is wonderful, because it leaves
% your vector intact, but it doesn't plot.
close all; clear all;
n = 10000; % lotsa points
n = floor(n/3); % make an even set of pairs
n = n * 3 - 1;  % ends with a pair
x = 1:n; % we'll make a sine wave, interrupted to pairs of points.
% For other use, bring your pairs in to a pair of empty x and y vectors,
% padding between pairs with nan in x and y.
y = sin(x/3);
ix = find(0 == mod(x,3)); % index 3, 6, 9, etc. will get...
x(ix) = nan; % nan.
y(ix) = nan; % nan.
figure;
plot(x,y,'b'); % quick to plot, quick to zoom.
grid on;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `line` for example

```
X=[1:10 ; 2*(1:10)];
Y=fliplr(X); 

line(X,Y)
```

Comment: I don't see how this matches my data structure.

Comment: Well, it's just to show usage.  Line is vectorized and plots lines in 2D without a for loop which is what I thought you were asking for.  Just create 2 matrices from the columns of your data. X from the 1st and 3rd, Y from the 2nd and 4th.  transpose both and input to line. use the plot handle if you want to manipulate how it's displayed.

Comment: OK, then edit your answer; because usage can be verified easily with the docs. My question was "how to draw lines between corresponding pairs without a loop", not "how to draw a line". FYI "line" can be replaced by "plot" in your solution, which is nice. However, both versions are pretty slow and result in plots that are slow to respond (to zoom, etc.). (I'm dealing with 1500 pairs of points; I would have expected better.)